# Adding an image in luatex

Tags: graphics, luatex

I would like to use Lua functions in order to reproduce the effect of `\includegraphics{testimg}`. This means that the image "testimg.pdf"
would appear centered in the following example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\centering

Some text.

\directlua{
  tex.print("Text from Lua.")
  a = img.new({filename="testimg.pdf", height="200bp"})
  img.write(a)
}

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

While the text does indeed appear centered, the image appears at the left of the page. Clearly, I am doing something wrong. Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you do with `img.write()` is to write the node directly into the output stream without any knowledge of the current state (the \centering). When you are inside a horizontal everything is fine. When you are in vertical mode, the node just gets insert into the stream, that is

[image]

The hlists all have a leftskip and a rightskip (for the `\centering`) and the image has none. You have to insert the leftskip and the rightskip yourself.

If you have graphviz installed, you can try the viznodelist (https://gist.github.com/pgundlach/556247) lua file to generate a gv file from the page:

```
\usepackage{atbegshi}
...
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \directlua{
     require("viznodelist")
     viznodelist.nodelist_visualize(tex.box["AtBeginShipoutBox"],"nodes.gv")
  }}
```

and look at the resulting file `nodes.gv`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to add the leftskip and rightskip?

Comment: @cefstat no, you have to do that manually (AFAICS).

Comment: @cefstat you could jump into horizontal mode (for example by saying `\leavevmode` but that might have some side effects, depending on your current situation. In your code above for example the "Text from Lua." gets written _after_ the image.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\directlua{
  tex.print("Text from Lua.")
  a = img.new({filename="testimg.pdf", height="200bp"})
  img.write(a)
}}
```

then it is centered together with the text.

Comment: Careful: this is not a "real" solution. See for example the order of the image and the text. A lot of surprises may come up.

Comment: sure. It makes only sense without text in the same line

Comment: By accident on my smartphone I have voted down on this answer, not noticed that, 3 hours passed and now I cannot cancel it. How to cancel my down vote?